# How do I parse JSON in android and show the list of data in ListVIew?

Tags: android, json

I am using a web service that returns JSON in response. I want to parse the response and crate a list of object. I Don't know how to show the parsed data in UI in android. where user can select one item form the list (i.e. Dubai mall or dubai media city or dubai festival).

```
public class MyLocation extends MapActivity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.location);

    initButtons();

    initMapView();
    initMyLocation();   
                    jObject=getJSONFile("http://loyaltier.com/app/mobile/code/places/Maps.php");
}
    private JSONObject getJSONFile(String URL) {
    JSONObject jObject=null;
    HttpGet httpGet=new HttpGet(URL); //http://loyaltier.com/app/mobile/code/places/Maps.php
    HttpClient httpClient=new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse httpResponse;
    StringBuilder stringBuilder=new StringBuilder();
    try{
        httpResponse=httpClient.execute(httpGet);
        HttpEntity httpEntity=httpResponse.getEntity();
        InputStream inputStream=httpEntity.getContent();
        int c;
        while((c=inputStream.read())!=-1){
            stringBuilder.append((char)c);
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try{
        jObject=new JSONObject(stringBuilder.toString());
    }catch(JSONException e){
        Log.e("Log_tags ", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
    }
    return jObject;
} 
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use jObject.getString(name); 
It returns the value mapped by name

Answer (score 0):

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/267023/Send-and-receive-json-between-android-and-php
I have use this code. Its pretty easy and straight-forward. 
You have to change the json format a little.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the JACKSON lib for parsing the response data. Following post has some example for parsing:

[GSON/Jackson in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7939632/gson-jackson-in-android)

http://w2davids.wordpress.com/android-json-parsing-made-easy-using-jackson/

Then you can use the [List View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html) to display the list of branch object. check [this out](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html) for example.

Comment: Can not access to JSON elements such as branch id and etc through JSON? I use only of JACKSON? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I write with GSON but the program not show log.i in gsonFoo method. Why? what is the problem?

Thing.java:

```
package org.example.loyaltier;

public class Thing {
     String branchId=null;
     String branchCode=null;
     String branchName=null;
     String branchTel=null;
     String address=null;
     String cityName=null;
     String countryName=null;
     String latitude=null;
     String longitude=null;
     String workingHours=null;
}
```

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MyLocation extends MapActivity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.location);
         try {
             Log.i("THISSSSSSSSS", "ISSSSSSSSS");
             Log.i("FFOOOORRRR", "YYOUUUUUUUUU");
             gsonFoo();
          } catch (Exception e1) {
         Log.i("catch", "catch");
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
   }
 }
 public void gsonFoo() throws Exception
 {
     Gson gson = new Gson();
     Thing thing = gson.fromJson(new                     FileReader("http://loyaltier.com/app/mobile/code/places/Maps.php"), Thing.class);
System.out.println(gson.toJson(thing));
    Log.i("GSOOOON", "FOOOO");
   }
 }
```